# Replace with variables with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to add some variable values to my html using the onclick jquery function:

For example:

```
<script>
$("#myid").click(function() {
    variable myTitleVar = 'MyTitle';

    //replace code here ... like appendto?

</script>

<div id="myid">Click here</div>
```

Stuff to be replaced:

```
<div id="title-container">{Value of myTitleVar Here}</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried looking at the jQuery documentation? In the future, if you're going to post a list of requirements and then try to turn it into a question by bolting a single sentence onto the end of it, please at least ask "How can I do this?" instead of "Is this possible?". As it stands, the only valid answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: Got it..thanks for the tip. I have changed it in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should just be able to do this:

```
$('#myid').click(function(){
    var title = 'MyTitle';
    $('#title-container').text(title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myid").click(function() {
    var myTitleVar = 'MyTitle';
    $('#title-container').text(myTitleVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To set content of div, use jQuery html() method documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$("#myid").click(function() {
    var myTitleVar = 'MyTitle';
    $('#title-container').html(myTitleVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `var` keyword, there is no `variable` keyword in JavaScript, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myid").click(function() {
      var myTitleVar = 'MyTitle';
      $('#title-container').text(myTitleVar);
   })
})
```

- [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't need declare variables.

if you declare before all:

```
var $title = $("#title-container")
```

Then, you always could set the value in any script

```
$title.text("I have changed title");
```